# mean of $Y=|X|$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the pdf $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ find the mean for $Y$.

I have calculated the pdf $g(y) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\frac{-y^2}{2}}$.

Then working out the E(Y)

$E(Y) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2y}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\vert_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy$

In the solutions that I have the last integral term doesn't exist. Where did I go wrong in my calculation or is there a reason why it is $=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you attempted to do some kind of integration by parts, where instead a simple substitution would suffice:  $$\int_{y=0}^\infty \frac{2y}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2} \, dy$$ with the substitution $$u = y^2/2, \quad du = y \, dy$$ gives $$\int_{u=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u} \, du = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left[ -e^{-u} \right]_{u=0}^\infty = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}. $$

Comment: make sense. thanks. Shouldnt integration by parts mathematically give the same answer though?

Comment: @LB2015 What is your choice of $u$, $du$, $v$, and $dv$ in your proposed integration by parts; that is to say, how would you apply the formula $$\int u \, dv = uv - \int v \, du?$$

Comment: $u = y$ and $dv = exp{-y^2/2}$

Comment: @LB2015 and if you choose $dv = e^{-y^2/2} \, dx$, what would $v$ be?

Comment: $\frac{-1}{y} exp(\frac{-y^2}{ 2})$ and thats where i get stuck .. because the $y$ doesnt disappear

Comment: wait i get it. if i take the derivative then it doesn't work. it's not equal. thanks!